# Use DP connected to discrete nvidia GPU with Gnome Wayland

Tags: arch-linux, nvidia, wayland, amd-graphics

I've got a laptop with both Ryzen and Nvidia graphics.

Unfortunately, it doesn't have a mux and my displayport is connected to the NVidia card.

Under XOrg, I can set the NVidia GPU as primary, and just render everything out of there. I've been unable to find and equivalent for Wayland.

To further complicate things, I'd like to be able to use both my HDMI and DP (the HDMI is connected to the Ryzen GPU) so I can have a couple of high refresh rate monitors on the go, rather than being limited to a single one.

Is this possible at this time?

For what it's worth, I'm running up-to-date arch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure *why* this works... But all I had to do was install the nvidia drivers, add `nvidia_drm.modeset=1` to my boot options and it seems to "just work".

There are a few glitches with scaling when moving windows between the monitors, but that's something I can happily live with.